Any straightened version of jogs like "ㄣ" in Unicode?
Here is U+3123 BOPOMOFO LETTER EN: "ㄣ".
Is there any "straightened out version"? I.e., please recommend a better Unicode character, where all angles are 90° Flipped is OK, mirrored is OK. Rotated fine.
I spent hours with gucharmap and couldn't find any in the entire Unicode!
Sure, there is
U+2301 ELECTRIC ARROW: "⌁"
but not only is it not straight, it also has an arrow attached.
U+05DC HEBREW LETTER LAMED: 'ל' even less straight.

Not sure I understand how this is a software request. You should have maybe asked for a web app to find that more easily instead.

U+07C6
߆
It's a N'Ko numeral (6).
It's under N'Ko in gucharmap.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%27Ko_script

The script has a few similarities to the Arabic script, notably its
direction (right-to-left)

I've used https://shapecatcher.com/ (Unicode character recognition).

Unicode is clearly missing four items:

Straight S
Rotated Straight S
Straight Z
Rotated Straight Z

You (me, Dan Jacobson) should make a proposal to add them.
You could mention rotation means 90° in either direction, as both directions produce the same result.
And mention what block of Unicode they should add them to, e.g., "Miscellaneous Technical".
Or maybe say "reflected Z" instead of "S".

Ah ha: └┐,┌┘┐  ┌└, ┘
